# Random/new text on page refresh and page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of facts that I wish to change on page refresh and/or page load.

All the solutions I've come across involve having a button, which I do not want.

```
function newFact() {
 var randomFact = Math.floor(math.random() * facts.length);
 document.getElementById('factDisplay').innerHTML = facts[randomFact]
}
```

So I've got a function that randomly pulls one string (fact) from a list of facts (var facts). I wish to make it such that every refresh/reload of the HTML page will generate a new fact.

**EDIT:** I called my script using `<body onload="newFact()">`. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: why do you need a button? Call the newFact() function on page load event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it as an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately invoked function expression) anywhere in your script.

```js
(function newFact() {
  var facts = ['Fact 1', 'Fact 2', 'Fact 183'];
  var randomFact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
  document.getElementById('factDisplay').innerHTML = facts[randomFact];
})();
```

```html
<div id="factDisplay"></div>
```

IIFEs get (forcibly) executed before any other normal functions in JS. So on every page load/refresh this will be executed first, and show different result each time.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your script at the bottom/footer of your page and call it, like so :

```js
const facts = ["1", "2", "3"];

!function newFact() {
  const randomFact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
  document.getElementById('factDisplay').innerHTML = facts[randomFact];
}();
```

```html
<div id="factDisplay"></div>
```