# How do I make the placeholder text of a text input randomly change on page refresh using only basic JS (NO jQuery please)

Tags: javascript, html

This one ALMOST helped, but then I tried it and didn't understand, like at ALL [Random/new text on page refresh and page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289294/random-new-text-on-page-refresh-and-page-load)
Current code in the HTML File relating to this:

```
 <input type="text" id="quot" name="quot" placeholder="Grass grows, birds fly, sun shines. and 
 brotha, I hurt people"><br>
```

and in the JS file:

```
const quotes = ["Grass grows, birds fly, sun shines. and brotha, I hurt people.", "If you keep going the way you're going. You're gonna have a bad time...", "I love the smell of napalm in the morning"]
function newQuote() {
    var randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    document.getElementById('quot').placeholder = quotes[randomQuote]
   }
```

so... any help would be appreciated

**Edit:** Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu for telling me to not use innerHTML, but it didn't make any difference...
please give a more step-by-step explanation in your replies (mostly because I'm stupid, this is **NOT** just me being an ass trying to get people to not give me suggestions. suggestions are still appreciated, it's just that I'll most likely not get it right)

All the code (in case something else is the problem):

**HTML:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" id="red" name="col" value="red">
        <label for="red">Rød</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="blu" name="col" value="blu">
        <label for="blu">Blå</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="blac" name="col" value="blac">
        <label for="blac">Svart</label><br>
        <label for="imag">Last opp bilde</label><br>
        <input type="file" id="imag" name="imag" accept="image/*" /><br><br>
        <label for="name">Navn:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Biggus Dickus"><br>
        <label for="phon">Tlf:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phon" name="phon" placeholder="det trenger du ikke, vi ringer deg"><br>
        <label for="adr">Adr:</label>
        <input type="text" id="adr" name="adr" placeholder="Jeg vet hvor du bor..."><br>
        <label for="quot">Quote:</label>
        <input type="Text" id="quot" name="quot" placeholder="Grass grows, birds fly, sun shines. and brotha, I hurt people"><br>
    </form>
    <div id="card"></div>
    <img id="bild" src="BeanDeepFried.png" alt="BEAN!">
    <h1>If you can read this then the guy writing the code has lost his damn mind because this is fucking impossible to do the way he wants</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#name{
    width: 704px
}
#phon{
    width: 719px
}
#adr{
    width: 714px
}
#quot{
    width: 700px
}
#bild{
    width: 200px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
const name = document.querySelector("#name");
const red = document.querySelector("#red");
const blu = document.querySelector("#blu");
const blac = document.querySelector("#blac");
const imag = document.querySelector("#imag");
console.log(imag)
const phon = document.querySelector("#phon");
const adr = document.querySelector("#adr");
const quot = document.querySelector("#quot");
const card = document.querySelector("#card");
const bild = document.querySelector("#bild");

var loadFile = function(event) {
    var image = document.getElementById('imag');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
document.getElementById('bild').src="image";

const quotes = ["Grass grows, birds fly, sun shines. and brotha, I hurt people.", "If you keep going the way you're going. You're gonna have a bad time...", "I love the smell of napalm in the morning"]
function newQuote() {
    var randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    document.getElementById('quot').placeholder = quotes[randomQuote]
   }
```

Comment: JS is case-sensitive, and when you want to set a placeholder, then set the value of placeholder, not innerHTML (which doesn't even exist in input elements).

Comment: Umh ... `math` doesn't exist, the code breaks because of an error is fired. Hit F12 to open the DevTools, you can see the error message in the Console tab.

Comment: Like @Teemu said, `math` (with small `m`) does not exist, it should be `Math.random` with a capital `M` at the beginning. Welcome to StackOverflow! +1 for sharing code and for the "NO jQuery please" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined function `newQuote`, but it is never called.

To call it whenever the page is loaded, add the following statement to the end of your script.js file:

```
newQuote();
```